# How to configure Search API with DDEV

Tags: drupal, ddev

Since the docs are not specific to Drupal, below is a Drupal specific answer.

How to connect search API to DDEV's solr, based on config from https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/additional-services/

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect Search API for Drupal 7 with Solr (https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr):

1. Add a new Solr server via `admin/config/search/search_api/add_server`, or edit an existing one.
2. Under "Solr host" write `<projectname>.ddev.local`
3. Under "Solr path" write `solr/dev`

Comment: Thanks so much for this. We're still struggling with how to manage specific user recipes so that they can easily be maintained. Could you please update this with info about which Drupal version(s) it covers, and what the prequisites are?

Comment: Just a note that the [ddev docs on solr](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/additional-services/#apache-solr)  now have quite a bit more about search_api configuration.